# Cross-platform way to get PIDs by process name in python

Tags: python, cross-platform, jython, hp-ux

Several processes with the same name are running on host. What is the cross-platform way to get PIDs of those processes by name using **python** or **jython**?

1. I want something like `pidof` but in python. (I don't have `pidof` anyway.)
2. I can't parse `/proc` because it might be unavailable (on HP-UX).
3. I do not want to run `os.popen('ps')` and parse the output because I think it is ugly (field sequence may be different in different OS).
4. Target platforms are Solaris, HP-UX, and maybe others.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use psutil (https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil), which works on Windows and UNIX:

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "python.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        print(proc)
```

On my machine it prints:

```
<psutil.Process(pid=3881, name='python.exe') at 140192133873040>
```

EDIT 2017-04-27 - here's a more advanced utility function which checks the name against processes' name(), cmdline() and exe():

```
import os
import psutil

def find_procs_by_name(name):
    "Return a list of processes matching 'name'."
    assert name, name
    ls = []
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        name_, exe, cmdline = "", "", []
        try:
            name_ = p.name()
            cmdline = p.cmdline()
            exe = p.exe()
        except (psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            continue
        if name == name_ or cmdline[0] == name or os.path.basename(exe) == name:
            ls.append(p)
    return ls
```

Comment: Unfortunately OS X does not allow you to access many attributes of a process (name, exe, cmdline), even if you only try to access those processes that are created by you. Unless you run the interpreter/script with sudo, that is.

Comment: Yes, that's a limitation of OSX (and it's the only platform behaving like that). There's nothing you can do about it except using sudo/setuid.

Comment: Update - this is now fixed for different methods, see:
https://code.google.com/p/psutil/issues/detail?id=297

Comment: In my environment `.name` was a method, not a property.

Comment: so how would this identify my process from among multiple python processes?

Comment: It shouldn't. The only way a process is uniquely identified as long as it's alive is via its PID (which can be reused after it's gone), but when you don't know the PID you might look for its name, or cmdline, or whatever.

Comment: It would be great to see psutil support for Jython. Some of it might work now, if psutil didn't rely on `sys.platform` (`'java1.8.0_45'` on my system) to determine the underlying OS; there is a [bug in reading /proc](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2358) that needs to be fixed; other parts using the C Extension API might once [Stefan's work](http://gsoc2015-jyni.blogspot.com/) is complete.

Comment: This example needs extra boilerplate for catching `NoSuchProcess`. Without it, it's impossible to iterate through `process_iter()` without hitting a `ZombieProcess` exception. Checking `is_running()` and `status()` are not enough to avoid this exception, at least on OS X.

Comment: On my platform(Windows 7 and Python 2.7) I couldn't get any information other than pid and name... Why no CMDLINE?

Comment: Unfortunately psutil uses a method that often fails for services... even though the user would otherwise have permission to get a limited set of features.  Needed to patch it to get it to play nice with restricted info and not toss PermissionError exceptions.

Comment: How did you patch it?

Answer (score 14):

There's no single cross-platform API, you'll have to check for OS. For posix based use /proc. For Windows use following code to get list of all pids with coresponding process names

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')
process_list = [(p.Properties_("ProcessID").Value, p.Properties_("Name").Value) for p in processes]
```

You can then easily filter out processes you need.
For more info on available properties of Win32_Process check out [Win32_Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This library doesn't come standard with Python, at least not with 2.7. Didn't check the other versions.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic yes and it is the `pywin32` package with builds http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/ the answer should have included this

Answer (score 13):

```
import psutil

process = filter(lambda p: p.name() == "YourProcess.exe", psutil.process_iter())
for i in process:
  print i.name,i.pid
```

Give all pids of "YourProcess.exe"

Comment: I hold no stake either way; I often hear people rant that List Comprehension is *always* the best way to filter a list because its faster. eg `process = [proc for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name == "YourProcess.exe"]`.

Answer (score 5):

A note on [ThorSummoner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550653/cross-platform-way-to-get-pids-by-process-name-in-python#comment45084163_14792920)

```
process = [proc for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name == "YourProcess.exe"].
```

I have tried it on Debian with Python 3, I think it has to be `proc.name()` instead of `proc.name`.

Answer (score 3):

First, Windows (in all it's incarnations) is a non-standard OS.

Linux (and most proprietary unixen) are POSIX-compliant standard operating systems.

The C libraries reflect this dichotomy.  Python reflects the C libraries.

There is no "cross-platform" way to do this.  You have to hack up something with [ctypes](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-ctypes.html) for a particular release of Windows (XP or Vista)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to find a purely python-based, portable solution without using /proc or command line utilities, at least not in python itself. Parsing os.system is not ugly - someone has to deal with the multiple platforms, be it you or someone else. Implementing it for the OS you are interested in should be fairly easy, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

For jython, if Java 5 is used, then you can get the Java process id as following:

```py
from java.lang.management import ManagementFactory

pid = int(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0])

print(pid)
```

This snippet will print your PID (in my case `23968`)

Comment: that works, but I want to get PID of another process (like pidof do but without using pidof)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, I'm afraid. Processes are uniquely identified by pid not by name. If you really must find a pid by name, then you will have use something like you have suggested, but it won't be portable and probably will not work in all cases.

If you only have to find the pids for a certain application and you have control over this application, then I'd suggest changing this app to store its pid in files in some location where your script can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
def get_process_by_name(name):
    import re, psutil
    ls = list()
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if hasattr(p, 'name'):
            if re.match(".*" + name + ".*", p.name()):
                ls.append(p)
    return ls
```

## returns Process object