# How to get the PID of a PyWin32 process

Tags: python, vsto, subprocess, pid, pywin32

I'm using the PyWin32 extensions to do some Microsoft Office calculations through my Python code.

This is how I start Word:

```
import win32com.client

wordApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
# calculations...
# Now, how do I get its PID?
```

What I am trying to figure out here is **how to get the wordApp process ID (PID)** since I am not using the `subprocess` module here and I can't just type `wordApp.pid`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing a similar thing, but dispatching excel object. In order to get the process Id, I do the following:

```
import win32process
import win32com
self.application = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
t, p = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(self.application.Hwnd)
```

From these variables, p is the process id (the one that shows in task manager).

Hope this helps, despite the time passed.

Comment: You need to add "import win32process" at top as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think myProcess is a reference to the Word object dispatched and cannot fetch you process information.

You might have to connect to WMI for getting process details like:

```
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
```

I hope I understood the question right and this helps.

Comment: I only need the process id (PID) of wordApp.

Comment: You can always filter on process name (winword.exe). Please see this link, related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550653/cross-platform-way-to-get-pids-by-process-name-in-python

Answer (score 0):

application = CreateObject("application_name")

print("You've got your process id %d" % application.ProcessID)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).