# How to get the PID of a PyWin32 PowerPoint process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

At some point, I can't use `Quit()`. So, I need to find the PID and kill the process using `psutil` or `os.kill`

I already look at existing answers on StackOverflow but can't find them for PowerPoint. I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785708/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-pywin32-process), and it works on Excel but not PowerPoint. On PowerPoint `Hwnd` does not return Hwnd ID as Excel does.

Code:

```
import win32process
import win32com.client

app = win32com.client.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
t, p = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(app.Hwnd)  # app.Hwnd returns "<bound method Hwnd of <COMObject PowerPoint.Application>>"
print('PowerPoint PID : ' + str(p))
```

Comment: What happens if you have `app.Hwnd()`?

Comment: I don't know if it has it, I can't find the documentation after all.

Comment: No, based on your output/error, I was asking what happens if you have `t, p = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(app.Hwnd())`. I didn't suggest looking into the docs or smt like that. Because the question is lacking the actual code output ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Try using the python multiprocessing libray and [multiprocessing.active_children](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.active_children) to get the child processes of the python process.