# Can I specify which instances of a program to kill with "TASKKILL"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.system, taskkill

I have the following code:

```
import os
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe")
```

I am aware that this command will forcefully kill the "notepad.exe" process.
What I would like to know is, can I make that command more specific?

If I had both "helloworld.txt" and "goodbyeworld.txt" open, could I edit the code in any way to only kill "goodbyeworld.txt", instead of "notepad.exe" in general?

Comment: If you can find the PID of the process that has a given file open, then just use `/PID <pid>` instead of `/IM <image>`.

Comment: If you know the PID sure, otherwise no. The OS in general only knows that x instances of a program is open. It doesn't know what the program has open in itself.

Comment: How would I go about finding the PID of the process?

Comment: You can, but you'll probably have to use balck magic, like reading window title, parsing it and finding what file is open.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550653/cross-platform-way-to-get-pids-by-process-name-in-python

Comment: Yes, thank you! I managed to achieve what I set out to do. Although to find the PID I found the Command Prompt to work best. "tasklist" displays all processes and their IDs".