# how to kill python program in linux using name of the program

Tags: python, linux

when i use `ps -ef |grep` i get the current running programs
if below shown are the currently running programs.How can i stop a program using the name of the program

```
user   8587  8577 30 12:06 pts/9    00:03:07 python3 program1.py

user   8588  8579 30 12:06 pts/9    00:03:08 python3 program2.py
```

eg. If i want to stop program1.py then how can i stop the process using the program name "program1.py"
.If any suggestions on killing the program with python will be great

Comment: not really a python question...more unix/shell

Answer (score 1):

By using `psutil` is fairly easy

```py
import psutil

proc = [p for p in psutil.process_iter() if 'program.py' in p.cmdline()]
proc[0].kill()
```

To find out the process from the process name filter through the process list with `psutil` like in [Cross-platform way to get PIDs by process name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550653/cross-platform-way-to-get-pids-by-process-name-in-python)

Comment: yeah i know that but. i wanted to know if there is a way to kill the process using program name

Comment: @sharath updated the answer with the program name ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this with the process name:

```
pkill -f "Process name"
```

For eg. If you want to kill the process "program1.py", type in:

```
pkill -f "program1.py"
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: no i also tried this. pkill python3 kills all programs but pkill program1.py doesnt kill the process.

Comment: when i looked for pgrep -l python i got all process but pgrep -l program1.py didnt give a output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `pkill` utility installed, you can just use:

```
pkill program1.py
```

If you don't, using more common Linux commands:

```
kill $(ps -ef | grep program1.py | awk '{print $2}')
```

If you insist on using Python for that, see [How to terminate process from Python using pid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856928/how-to-terminate-process-from-python-using-pid)

Answer (score 0):

grep the program and combine add pipe send the output in another command.
1. see program `ps -ef`.
2.search program `grep program`.
3. remove the grep that you search because is appear in the search process `grep -v grep`.
4.separate the process  to kill with awk `awk '{ print $2 }'`
5. apply cmd on the previous input `xarks kill -9`

```
ps -ef  | grep progam | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
```

see here for more:
  about [pipe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/) , [awk](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/), [xargs](https://shapeshed.com/unix-xargs/)

with python you can use os:

```
template = "ps -ef  | grep {program} | grep -v grep | awk '{{ print $2 }}' | xargs kill -9"
import os
os.system(template.format(program="work.py"))
```