# pywin32 Scheduled Tasks PID

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, win32com

I'm trying to use win32com.client in order to interact with scheduled tasks on windows.

So far it's working fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the PID of a running process created by the scheduled task.

Documentation says to look at the value of IRunningTask::get_EnginePID method. However, while  I can do something like:

```
    scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
    scheduler.Connect()
    folder = scheduler.GetFolder('\\')
    task = folder.GetTask('Name of created task')
    task.State
    task.Name
```

I'm not sure how to access this EnginePID attribute as `task.EnginePID` or anything like that doesn't work.

So for example, I have a task that launches calc.exe.  I want to find the PID of the calc.exe or whatever process spawned by the scheduled task.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2241047/9388050 using that code you could find your process ID. For specific task, I'm not sure but you can assign the execution time to a variable when you started the task, and put filter 10 seconds. You can get PID the task your script created. Obviously better way exist, but I think this way can work also for you.